# In SwiftUI, trying to use accessibility(sortPriority: to focus VoiceOver on some text

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on a multiple choice app in SwiftUI.  I am writing this app with VoiceOver users in mind.  My app puts a question on the screen with some choices then a next question button.  After the user activates the Next Question button, the next question and choices show on the screen.  I am trying to get VoiceOver to focus on the text for the next question by using the accessibility(sortPriority: modifier.  Since that text is the only accessibility(sortPriority: modifier I have, I set it to 1.  When the first question is posted, VoiceOver reads the text of the first question.  Whenever the VoiceOver user activates the next question button, the VoiceOver focus stays on that button.  Below is some of the code.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            Text(questionText).accessibility(sortPriority: 1)


        }
        ForEach(choices, id: \.self) { choice in
            Button(action: {
                self.answer = choice
            }) {
                Text(choice)
            }
        }

        if self.answer != "" && self.answer != self.correctAnswer {
            Text("Nope, try again.")

        } else if self.answer == self.correctAnswer {
            Text("That was the correct answer.")


                    }
        if self.questionNumber < self.questions.questions.count-1 {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.questionNumber += 1
                            if self.theQuestion.count < 6 {
                                self.questionNumber += 1

                            }
                            self.answer = ""
                       }) {
                            Text("Next Question")
                        }
                    }
    }.accessibilityElement(children: .contain)

    /*out of VStack
*/
}
```

}

Comment: I suspect it has to be a direct child of the container that contains .accessibilityElement(children:.contain)
What happens if you take out the extra VStack ?